# Как решить классическую проблему размещения двух элементов в один ряд в html / css

Tags: html, css

Приветствую вас уважаемые граждане stack overflow. У меня проблема с размещением двух элементов в ряд(смотрите фрагмент кода ниже). Я буду благодарен за любую помощь или совет.

Конечный результат должен быть такой: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мои потуги привели к этому: [image]

Что иконка соц.сети, что описание, должно работать синхронно как одно целое. Однако их нужно разделить, чтоб позже можно было отключить текст(display: none) и оставить только иконку. Вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вариант с

```
.social__icon {
  display: inline-flex; 
  align-items: center;
```

даёт такой результат: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
ol,
ul,
li,
menu {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.social__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.social__icon {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
}

.social__icon img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.social__icon span {}

.social__icon:active {
  background: #4B9200;
  color: #4B9200;
}

.social__icon:hover {
  animation: shake 500ms ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(2deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(3deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <ul class="social__list">
    <li>
      <a class="social__icon" href="https://en-gb.facebook.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
        <img src="../../assets/icons/social/fb.svg" alt="">
        <span>Facebook</span>
      </a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="social__icon" href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
        <img src="../../assets/icons/social/twtr.svg" alt="">
        <span>Twitter</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="social__icon" href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
        <img src="../../assets/icons/social/inst.svg" alt="">
        <span>Instagram</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="social__icon" href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
        <img src="../../assets/icons/social/youtube.svg" alt="">
        <span>Youtube</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Нет никакой классической проблемы. У вас два блока. 1 блок - это блок с фоном, радиусом и картинкой в центре, 2 блок - текст, оба они обернуты в общего родителя. Разместите 2 блока рядом, используя `display: flex` у их общего родителя.

Comment: Родительский блок и есть фон) размером в  width: 26px;
  height: 26px; это серый эллипс внутри которого иконка img, в нем же находится span который уже не влазит в width: 26px;
  height: 26px;  и поэтому его и выбрасывает за борт. Почему так, спросите? Дело в том что анимация и hover должны работать только на иконке и тексте синхронно. А позже при сужении экрана, текст будет скрываться и останется только иконка

Comment: Это никак не объясняет вашу разметку. Что вам мешает использовать селекторы текста и иконки при наведении на общего родителя? `.parrent:hover .icon` и `.parrent:hover .text`

Answer (score 1):

Что-то типа такого?

```css
ol,
ul,
li,
menu {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.social__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.social__icon {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
}

.social__icon img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.social__icon :where(img, span) {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.social__icon:active {
  background: #4B9200;
  color: #4B9200;
}

.social__icon:hover {
  animation: shake 500ms ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(2deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(3deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <ul class="social__list">
    <li>
      <a class="social__icon" href="https://en-gb.facebook.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
        <img src="https://icons.getbootstrap.com/assets/icons/facebook.svg" alt="">
        <span>Facebook</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="social__icon" href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
        <img src="https://icons.getbootstrap.com/assets/icons/twitter.svg" alt="">
        <span>Twitter</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="social__icon" href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
        <img src="https://icons.getbootstrap.com/assets/icons/instagram.svg" alt="">
        <span>Instagram</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="social__icon" href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
        <img src="https://icons.getbootstrap.com/assets/icons/youtube.svg" alt="">
        <span>Youtube</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Если вас интересует конкретно решение, то вот:

```
.social__icon :where(img, span) {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Про псевдокласс `:where` - [на MDN](//developer.mozilla.org/Web/CSS/:where)

Answer (score 0):

```css
ol,
ul,
li,
menu {
  list-style: none;
}


.social__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.social__wrap-img {
 width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.5);
}

.social__icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.social__icon img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: center;
}

.social__icon span {}

.social__icon:active {
  background: #4B9200;
  color: #4B9200;
}

span {
margin-left: 5px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s linear;
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
  }

.social__icon:hover span {
  animation: shake 500ms ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(2deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(3deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <ul class="social__list">
    <li>
      <a class="social__icon" href="https://en-gb.facebook.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
      <div class="social__wrap-img">
          <img src="../../assets/icons/social/fb.svg" alt="">
         </div>
        <span>Facebook</span>
      </a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: hover эффект у вас работает на весь блок, т.е. красит весь задний фон, когда должно красить зеленым только текст справа и задний фон иконки.

Comment: @Mezamorta у вас в задаче написано выровнять элементы, их выровняли

Answer (score 0):

Ребята выше написали решение, но что бы понять надо оценить сам макет (схематично отобразил задачу)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть куча способов как расположить элементы друг под другом, но мы остановимся на флексах

(Красный)Первое что нужно сделать это расположить их друг под другом(display:flex; flex-direction: column;), элементы у нас теперь в столбик

(Зеленый) Идем глубже у нас есть блок и текст, условно мы знаем что иконка блок с иконкой занимает место в этом блоке, что бы далеко не ходить мы иконку выравниваем и под блок в котором иконка оставляем место (flex: 0 0 2rem; max-width: 2rem; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;)

(Оранжевый) Мы хотим что бы элементы не "слипались" реализуем им пространство (.elem+.elem{ margin-top: твое расстояние;})

Дальше уже дело кастомизации элементов, мы сейчас разобрали почему и как